# Testing MUI5 Select with testing-library

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, user-event

I'm using create-react-app 5 (with React 17, Jest, and testing-library), along with MUI 5. I'd like to test clicking a simple [Select](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-select/) menu, and making sure the menu options appear. I tried the following:

```js
  it('shows the menu', async () => {
    render(<FormControl fullWidth>
      <InputLabel id="testselect-label">Age</InputLabel>
      <Select
        labelId="testselect-label"
        id="testselect"
        data-testid="testselect"
        label="Age"
        value={10}
      >
        <MenuItem value={10}>Ten</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
        <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    </FormControl>);
    const selectButton = screen.getByTestId("testselect");
    userEvent.click(selectButton);
    expect(await screen.findByRole('presentation')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

But the menu (which has `role="presentation"`) doesn't appear, so the test fails. If I call `screen.debug()` after the test, it prints the Select button, but not the menu.

I've already seen this [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59567234/materialui-react-testing-library-unit-test-select-menuitem-breaks-after-upgra), where I found that MUI5's Select responds to mouseDown events rather than click events. But `userEvent.click` sends both, so that's not the issue. I also tried `fireEvent.mouseDown` with no luck.

I also tried a debugger, and as far as I can tell, the `onMouseDown` handler of the relevant MUI component (`SelectInput`) is never called.

Does anyone have an example of this that works?

Comment: You need to use `mouseDown` instead of `click`.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I mentioned that above -- `userEvent.click` calls `mouseDown`, so that part's okay. I was clicking the wrong element though -- it needs to be the `button`.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you need to click the `button` element:

```js
    const selectButton = within(screen.getByTestId('testselect')).getByRole('button');
    userEvent.click(selectButton);
```

Comment: You are right! Work for me!